# rethinkdb get all record not in other document

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

we are using rethinkdb with nodejs. i have a user table and i want to get all isActive users which are not in userdetail table

**User Table**

```
{
"id":  "1" ,
"fName":  "A" ,
"lName":  "B" ,
"isActive": true
}
{
 "id":  "2" ,
"fName":  "C" ,
"lName":  "D" ,
"isActive": true
}
{
"id":  "3" ,
"fName":  "E" ,
"lName":  "F" ,
"isActive": true
}
{
"id":  "4" ,
"fName":  "G" ,
"lName":  "H" ,
"isActive": false
 }
 {
 "id":  "5" ,
 "fName":  "I" ,
 "lName":  "J" ,
 "isActive": true
  }
```

**userDetails**

```
{
"id":  "12" ,
"users":  [{"userId":"1"},{"userId":"2"}]
}
```

Now i want all isActive user except with id 1 and 2

so for i have tried following query but its not working

```
r.db("mydb").table("users").filter( function(u) 
{ return r.db("mydb").
 table("userdetails")("userId").contains( u("id")         
 ).not(); })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this what you may want

```
r.table('userdetails')('users').concatMap(r.row('userId')).coerceTo('ARRAY').do(
   function(userdetails) {
    return r.table('user').filter(function(user) {
      return user('isActive').and(userdetails.contains(user('id')).not())
   })
})
```

Though it may not perform very well